# How to incorporate a list into a SQL Query in Python

Tags: python, csv

I've prepared a list in Python, and would like to use that list to filter the items I query from a SQL database.

I have a query like this:

```
sql_query = "
    SELECT item
    FROM database
    WHERE item IN (*list*) "
```

And want to place a list that I prepared earlier in the script in the place of list. How would I do this? %s and %d don't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the SQL library being used (which could make this easier), the safest way would be to use a `%s` (or `?`, or other appropriate parameter marker) for each item in the list, and pass the list in the parameters. Example:

```
sql_query = """
    SELECT item
    FROM database -- This is actually a table.
    WHERE item IN ({})
""".format(','.join(['?'] * len(items)))

cursor.execute(sql_query, items)
```

This will create a query like:

```
SELECT item
FROM database
WHERE item IN (?,?,...)
```

Which is still safe from SQL injection. If `items` is empty, this will fail with a syntax error because `item IN ()` is not valid in any SQL database that I'm aware of.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `?` and not `%s`?

Comment: What library are you using? Because it depends entirely on the SQL library you're using as to whether you use `?`, `%s`, or some other marker.

Comment: Ahh, I usually use pyodbc with `?` bind variables.

Comment: Did you mean to put ' * len(items)' inside the join function and outside the one element list?

Comment: @goldisfine Yep, that's exactly what I meant so that you get `len(items)` many `?`s joined by `,`s.

Comment: But shouldn't it be inside the join() method to achieve that goal?

Comment: @goldisfine If I did `','.join(['?' * len(items)])` --> `','.join(['??...'])` --> `'??...'` which is not `'?,?,...'`. If you mean `','.join('?' * len(items))`, then that would give the same result as `','.join(['?'] * len(items))`. But using `['?'] * N` seems to be faster than `'?' * N` in my tests (technically `('?',) * N` was slightly faster than the list but it is less readable).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for this thorough clarification. I actually ended up not using place holders, and instead just using the cursor.execute(Request_string.format(','.join(request_info_to_insert)) and that worked. request_info_to_insert is what I would have inserted using placeholders.

Comment: @goldisfine No problem. Just be aware that not using placeholders can leave you open to SQL injection which is mainly a concern if the data is from a non-trusted source like a web-page.